# Generate date string with ToString("u") and with a T before the hour

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm developing a C# library with .NET Framework 4.5.

I need to generate this date string: `2015-12-01T07:54:20Z`
But now I'm generating this date string: `2015-12-01 07:54:20Z` (the same that previous one but with out the `T`).

To generate that date I'm using this code: `DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("u")`

How can I generate the other date string with the T?

Comment: Don't use `DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()`; use `DateTime.UtcNow`. It is cleaner and also more efficient. `DateTime.Now` converts UTC time to local time and that is a non-trivial thing to do.

Comment: Is `12` or `01` for months?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your format (without the trailing `Z`) is called the [sortable format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx#Sortable), and it has the pre-defined format specifier `"s"`:

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("s") + "Z"
```

yields

```
2015-12-18T09:04:58Z
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write whole format `DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")`

or use less elegant solution `ToString("u").Replace(" ","T")`

HH is for 24h format and hh is for 12h format

Answer (score 2):

Either

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fffffffzzz");
```

give you **2015-12-18T13:57:31.2311892-04:00**

or

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o");
```

give you **2015-12-18T14:01:54.9571247Z**

Comment: Have you _ever_ read the question? These are not what OP wants.

Comment: You have a problem with the backslashes in your string. Either escape them or use a verbatim string literal (`@"..."`).

Comment: And your first example won't _even_ compile.